# Смена языка в IOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios

Как в симуляторе сменить язык (чтобы можно было протестировать разные локализации). 
В одной статье писалось что нужно так менять Settings->General->International->Language->Русский

Но в симуляторе нет настроек. И вообще данного пути в симуляторе нет.

[image]

Comment: Странно у меня все есть. Может это связанно с настройками Mac os x?

Comment: А зачем Вы удалили предыдущий вопрос? Можно было его просто закрыть, раз он был отвечен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тапните на home (или горячая клавиша cmd + shift + h) и просвайпите до первого экрана, там будут настройки - вы их просто не нашли, Единственное что - может придется перезапустить симмулятор, смена локали иногда не сразу применяется к приложениям

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 1):

Вообще удобнее менять локаль создав новую схему проекта и прописывать там необходимый язык. [Здесь](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/07/22/using-launch-arguments-to-test-localizations.html) подробно написано про это.